# validate a textbox value serverside using jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have list of orders when user enter a value in textbox on blur I wanted to validate that value on serverside and then display a right or wrong icons based on true or false from server. I am using struts2, jquery.

I am very poor in ajax so please help me answer much detailed as possible

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** Thank you for your responses, I have tried [Fluidbyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957500/fluidbyte) solution but in response I got the entire html. My entries in different places as follows.

struts.xml

```
<action name="validate" class="orders" method="validate"/>
```

jsp

```
<td><s:textfield name="serial" id="serial" theme="simple"/></td>
<td><SPAN id="result"></SPAN> </td>
```

Action class

```
public String validate() {
result = myOrdSvc.validate(value);
return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * @param result
 *            the result to set
 */
public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

/**
 * @return the result
 */
public String getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

orders.js

```
         $('#serial').blur(function(){
            $.post('validate',{ value: $(this).val() },function(data){
               $("#result").html(data);
            });
        });
```

The result **"data"** is entirely an html not just **"true"** or **"false"** which I am returning.

Comment: So you want us to implement it for you? what have you tried? what's not working? you're poor in `ajax` Good, you know what you need and where is your problem. **Learn AJAX!** in other words:  [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: appreciate your comment, surely I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to the [Fluidbyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957500/fluidbyte) solution the change in Action class are,

**Thanks to [Fluidbyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957500/fluidbyte) again**.

1) Change return type to void

2) used [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to write the result to jsp.

```
public void validate() {
   result = myOrdSvc.validate(value);
   PrintWriter writer = ServletActionContext.getResponse().getWriter();
   writer.write(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to get a response from server-side:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $.post('path/to/file.ext',{ value: $(this).val() },function(data){
       // 'data' is whatever the server returns...
    });
});
```

On the server-side you would get a POST with the name 'value' that you could then evaluate.

The callback function returns 'data' which contains whatever your script returns

Comment: data always returns me entire help. my struts.xml entry is like this         <action name="validateSN" class="fulfillmyorders" method="validateSN">
    <result>/pages/orders.jsp</result>
        </action> what should be changed in this entry

Answer (score 0):

make an `jQuery ajax` call to a server page and let the server give a response and based on that show the relevant image

```
$(function(){

  $("#txtUserName").keyup(function(){
    $.get("someserverpage.php?key="+$(this).val(),function(data){
      //check value in data variable and do whatever you want to do (show hide image)
    });

  });    

});
```